# Как записать переменную в JSON при помощи pushState() в одном контроллере и получить эту переменную на другой странице в другом контроллере AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

При нажатии на кнопку перехода на другую страницу вначале в контроллере `AngularJS` я вызываю по `ng-click` функцию, в которой выполняю запись значения переменной `myvar`:

```
window.history.pushState({myvar: значение_переменной}, null, url)
```

Далее выполняю переход `window.location.href('адрес второй страницы, на которой нужно получить переменную myvar')`. Оказываюсь на второй странице.Как мне получить JSON-данные с моей переменной `myvar` с первой страницы из `history`, чтобы использовать в этом контроллере `AngularJS` для второй страницы?

Уточнение:
У каждой страницы свой angular.module, контроллеры не связаны между собой

Comment: Можно использовать $rootScope

Answer (score 1):

Пример примитивный... Но сути не меняет.В отличие от $scope, $rootScope, имеет один экземпляр и доступен во всем приложении, и можно использовать для передачи разных данные от контроллера к контроллеру.

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $scope.saveSomeData = function () {
        $rootScope.someData = {'data': true};
    };
}]);


app.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    alert($rootScope.someData);
}]);
```

Comment: спасибо. А такой вариант возможен, если для каждой страницы свой отдельный angular.module?